# Cordova. Крос доменный запрос не работает

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cross-domain

Пытаюсь собрать приложение на Cordova. Все хорошо. App собирается и успешно запускается в эмуляторе. Проблема встала, когда хочу сделать AJAX запрос к локальному серверу.

Кстати, сервер на ExpressJS и у него разрешены кросс доменные запросы.
Так же в /etc/hosts прописана ссылка на "127.0.0.1 test.loc"

В настройках Cordova в файле config.xml прописано

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://test.loc*" />
```

В index.html установил тег

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; connect-src *">
```

Для jQuery прописал флаг

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

Делаю билд, запускаю эмулятор. Подключаюсь консолью для дебага. Делаю реквест к серверу

```
http://test.loc:3000/api/auth/login
```

И получаю ошибку

```
POST http://test.loc:3000/api/auth/login net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Дальше мысли кончились. Гугл тоже не помог. Все что находил - не помогло. Если кто сталкивался, подскажите куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Само приложение сконфигурировано правильно. Проблема оказалась в ином. Сервер у меня запущен на локальном хосте. Когда стартует эмулятор, для него само приложение и есть localhost. И локальный сервер он попросту не видит. К внешним серверам без проблем отправляю данные и получаю ответ.

Вопрос закрыт.